# Question about forced damped oscillators

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is from my linear algebra book:

Find the function $f(t)$ of the form $f(t)=a \cdot cos(2t)+b \cdot sin(2t)$ such that $f''(t)+2f'(t)+3f(t)=17cos(2t)$

All I've figured out so far is that $f'(t)=d/dt[a \cdot cos(2t)+b \cdot sin(2t)]=-2a \cdot sin(2t) + 2b \cdot cos(2t),$ and $f''(t)=-4a \cdot cos(2t) - 4b \cdot sin(2t)$
I don't know if I'm going the right way with this or not, but in the context of your first day in Linear Algebra, how should I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

HINT...you need to find the values of $a$ and $b$, so plug your expressions for the first and second derivatives into the DE and compare coefficients of $\cos$ and $\sin$. This will give you a simultaneous equation to solve for $a$ and $b$.